# Is there a quick way to quickly delete the constrains of a selected element in the Xcode size inspector tab?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, storyboard

While working with Xcode 6.1.1 within storyboards is there a quick way to quickly delete the constrains of a selected element that show in the size inspector tab without having to go and look it up in the very the long list of constrains that show on the left pane?

Maybe I'm missing something like a keystroke because when I have to make a change to that element of the storyboard some of the constrains no longer apply and I want to delete them and recreate them quickly.

[image: size inspector]

Instead of having to look for it in a long list to be able to select it there and delete it:

[image: long list of constrains]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clic on the constraint and simply tap the delete key, you can select multiple contraints using cmd + clic

Comment: My problem is that my keyboard is not an apple one but an HP one. For some reason the delete button wasn't doing it. After you posted this I tried the delete and didn't work but since you said it worked I tried the backspace one instead and that one did it so thanks a lot for the answer that got me in the right track and found the solution. For some non-Apple keyboards it's the backspace one the one that works. That will save me a lot of grief. Thanks again.